# Query Table Without SELECT Access

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I work at a large corporation. I do not have SELECT access to a certain table, let's call it NO_ENTRY. I can view NO_ENTRY's schema and am only interested in two columns. Without asking my dba, is it **possible** to see some or all data in these two columns?

If it's relevant I do have SELECT access to at least one view that references NO_ENTRY; it just doesn't have the columns of interest. It's possible that I have SELECT access to other views that have the columns of interest.

I've tried finding tables with similar data sources but none exist. Is it possible to query Teradata for a list of views that I have SELECT access to and that reference the two columns of interest in NO_ENTRY?

If not, are there any other **possible** workarounds to see NO_ENTRY's two columns of interest?

Comment: Did you receive a satisfactory answer? If so, you might want to put closure to your question by marking one the answers accepted.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no reasonable possibilities. If the DBA has exposed some of NO_ENTRY's fields through a view and disallowed SELECT on NO_ENTRY, those are the only fields you can access. If you really need access to the 2 fields that you don't current have access to but you need them, just ask the DBAs really nicely with a reasonable reason why you need access to those 2 fields.

Comment: You may also need to ask the business owner of the data source if you may have access to those columns. Sometimes the DBA’s hands are tied on handing out access to certain parts of the data model.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven’t exhausted this route, seek out the data dictionary or data model from your data modeling or DBA team. I’m not sure the sensitivity of your environment and what information is made available to developers or end users, but in many environments a data dictionary is made available to help users navigate the data model or semantic access layer they have been given access to use.

If the data dictionary, data modelers, and DBA’s are unwilling to help, you can utilize the DBC views to see what you can find. The “X” Views in DBC limit users to seeing only those objects they created or have been granted permission to access. Poking around here should not send up any red flags. Alternatively, depending on your environment, you may also have the ability to query the non-X views (use the ones that end with a “V” to account for UNICODE and long object names).

If the columns are not aliased in the view definitions, you may be able to find what you are interested in using DBC.ColumnsV or DBC.ColumnsXV.

```
SELECT DatabaseName
     , TableName
     , ColumnName
  FROM DBC.ColumnsXV
 WHERE ColumnName = ‘{ColumnName}’
   AND TableName = ‘{ViewName}’
   AND DatabaseName = ‘{DatabaseName}’;
```

If the columns are aliased, you will have a more difficult time with your search. You can look at the `CreateText` or `LastAlterText` in DBC.TablesXV using pattern searches (e.g. LIKE, POSITION, REGEXP_INSTR, etc.).